# What is the name of the font used in this logo?

Tags: fonts, logo

i am looking for this type of typeface for my new logo, i try to upload this image on whatfont(image to font chacker by myfont) but i can't get specific result(https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/marksimonson/changeling-neo/) to the perfect industry type curve fonts. so please help me out.

[image]

Comment: A quick Google search found a couple of websites which you can use to upload the image and it will try to detect it.

https://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=how%20to%20find%20what%20font%20is%20used%20in%20a%20graphic&oq=how%20to%20find%20what%20font%20is%20used%20in%20a%20graphic&aqs=chrome..69i57.8623j0j

Comment: Try using What The Font, I haven't personally used it, but have heard good things about it. Last I heard, it is still free! Myfonts.com/whatthefont

Comment: Have you checked out our font identification help page?

Answer (score -1):

It might be a version of Space Colony
https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/flat-it/space-colony/bold/

Comment: Hi Marc, would you be able to provide a screenshot sample as well?

Comment: When answering font questions you should include a picture of the font.

Answer (score -1):

It looks similar to [Space Age](http://www.dafont.com/space-age.font), with some modifications (cropped ends, crossbar on the G shortened, custom swoop on the A, etc).

[image]

I doubt you'll find an exact replica of the font though – all of these 'spacey' fonts seem to be inspired by the classic NASA typeface ([there's a free version here](http://www.dafont.com/nasalization.font)), but you'll need to play around with any of them to get your desired result. Good luck!